# Why the table data is not updated immediately after performing an action for the table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table that has an action to delete..like this:

```
 const deleteRow = (row) => {
    let indexOfDeleted = -1;
    let data = tableData;
    data.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (item.instrumentId === row.instrumentId) {
          indexOfDeleted = index;
      }
  })
  data.splice(indexOfDeleted, 1);
  setTableData(data)
  };
```

The data is deleted but I have to refresh it so that it is not displayed in the table.It does not seem to be rerender. What should I do?
for table:

```
 const schema = {
    columns: [
      {
        field: "persianCode",
        title: "title",
      },
    ],
    operations: [
      {
        title: "delete",
        icon: (
          <DeleteIcon
            className={clsx(classes.operationsIcon, classes.deleteIcon)}
          />
        ),
        action: (row) => deleteRow(row),
        tooltipColor: theme.palette.color.red,
      }
    ],
  };
```

Comment: Don't know if that's the issue, but use the spread operator in order to clone `tableData` instead of modifying it - `let data = [...tableData]`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state variable, in your `deleteRow` function. You should update the state with a copied array:

```
 const deleteRow = (row) => {
    setTableData(table => table.filter(data => data.instrumentId !== row.instrumentId))
  };
```

Instead of finding the index and splicing it, you can just use the `filter` function. Since it returns a new array, we don't worry about mutating the state variable!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use Spread operator to reflect changes in react dom..

```
 const deleteRow = (row) => {
    let indexOfDeleted = -1;
    let data = tableData;
    data.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (item.instrumentId === row.instrumentId) {
          indexOfDeleted = index;
      }
  })
  data.splice(indexOfDeleted, 1);
  setTableData([...data])  /// like this
  };
```

Comment: This is still mutating the state variable.

Comment: use slice prototype  instead of splice